# Getting reference to FXML ImageView

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am making a game in JavaFX , for which I have 5x9 grid of ImageViews and also some Labels. When I try to get reference to label , I am successful. However , when I try to get reference to ImageView , I get nullPointerException.

Here is how root is declared :

```
FXMLLoader loaderTwo = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/game/levelTwo.fxml"));
Parent rootTwo = loaderTwo.load();
this.handlerTwo = loaderTwo.getController();
```

Here is FXML part of label :

```
<Label fx:id="sunCountLabel" layoutX="121.0" layoutY="15.0" minHeight="72.2891845703125" prefHeight="88.0" prefWidth="203.0" text="Label">
  <font>                                                                                                                                  
    <Font name="Gabriola" size="60.0" />                                                                                                  
  </font>                                                                                                                                 
</Label>
```

FXML part of Image view :

```
<ImageView fx:id="OneFive" fitHeight="180.0" fitWidth="180.0" layoutX="892.0" layoutY="102.0">
  <effect>                                                                                   
    <DropShadow height="1.0" radius="0.0" width="1.0" />                                     
  </effect>                                                                                  
  <image>                                                                                    
    <Image url="@../media/half.png" />                                                       
  </image>                                                                                   
</ImageView>
```

This is where I refer to them :

```
this.root = this.map.getLevel(2).getRoot();
Label l = (Label)this.root.lookup("#sunCountLabel");
ImageView i = (ImageView)this.root.lookup("OneFive");
System.out.println(i==null);
l.setText("1999");
```

**Issue is that Label is working correctly but Imageview gives nullPointerException**
I can't see why ?
Also , the scene is loading perfectly , no issues with image address etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector you're using is a type selector, i.e. it would only work, if a node returned `"OneFive"` from the [`getTypeSelector` method](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#getTypeSelector()). `ImageView` doesn't do this.

You probably wanted to use the id selector. This requires you to insert a `#` at the start of the selector string:

```
ImageView i = (ImageView)this.root.lookup("#OneFive");
```

I strongly recommend injecting the `ImageView` to a field in the controller though and accessing the `ImageView` via the controller. Also note that there are cases when `lookup` doesn't work. Looking up content inside a `ScrollPane` e.g. does not work before the first layout pass, since the node structure the `content` is added to is created during the first layout pass.

Comment: Problem solved , thank you so much. Just a piece of advice : I am 45 tiles and some 15 more ImageViews (using them as buttons). Plus , I am using Anchor Pane. Will injecting really help in this scenario , given the huge number of objects. Everything is working fine with my way also.

Comment: @AdityaSinghRathore With that many tiles/image views I would recommend creating them via a loop in the controller, if possible, rather than declaring each one in FXML individually. Then use some data structure(s) (e.g. list, map, etc.) for storing references to those tiles/image views.

Comment: @AdityaSinghRathore Imho fxml should also be considered code. Boilerplate code is a bad idea and your fxml seems to contain a lot of it. Consider setting up this part of the scene using java code. E.g. using a loop in the `initialize` method can reduce the size of the fxml drastically, allows you to update all of those tiles by modifing a single part of your code (the one creating the tile inside the loop) and also allows you to store the nodes in a way that suits your needs, e.g. in an array, a list, map, or whatever.

Comment: If I recall correctly (and I might not), in the past, in order to use an `id` selector, it wasn't enough to just have `fx:id` defined in the FXML, I also needed an `id` attribute, for example `<Label fx:id="sunCountLabel" id="sunCountLabel"...>`.  Perhaps I don't recall correctly or perhaps the FXML loader implementation changed in later versions to also set a css id matching an fx:id.

Comment: The only thing I recall is that using both attributes you can inject the node to a field with a name different to the css id...

Comment: Looked up the implementation, since at least Java 8, there is an annotation `com.sun.javafx.beans.IDProperty`.  The `Node` class defines this as `@IDProperty("id")`, the FXMLLoader looks up the annotation `IDProperty idProperty = value.getClass().getAnnotation(IDProperty.class);` and sets it `properties.put(idProperty.value(), fx_id);` with the comment "set fx:id property value to Node.id only if Node.id was not already set".  So that is how you end up getting the css id set to the `fx:id` by default.